# Can you override the Navigation Controllers 'InteractivePopGestureRecognizer' action?

Tags: xamarin.ios, uinavigationcontroller, uigesturerecognizer

I'm searching for ways to implement a swipe gesture recognizer which only triggers when you swipe from the outer left side of the screen to the right. We need the gesture to open our custom SideMenu. I tried to use a simple `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` with the `SwipeDirection` property set to right, but that gets triggered on every swipe from left to right, no matter what the startpoint of the swipe is.

Ideally, we want the animation of it to look and feel like the `InteractivePopGestureRecognizer` of a `UINavigationController`. We are already using a NavigationController, which pushed our MainView over our IntroView. Now, we disable the `InteractivePopGestureRecognizer`, so you aren't able to go back to the IntroView. That's our problem. If it is possible, we don't want to disable the gesture of the `NavigationController`, but change the action of it. So the swipe from the far left side of the screen to the right would not pop the current `viewcontroller`, but open our SideMenu.

Is it possible to override the `InteractivePopGestureRecognizer` to change the action of it? If this isn't possible, do you have another idea on how to create the exact same gesture recognizer? It has to be possible somehow because many apps only open their SideMenu if your startpoint of the gesture is the left  (or right) side of the screen. (e.g. Reddit)

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use **[Touch Events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/touch/touch-in-ios#touch-events)** and **UISwipeGestureRecognizer** to do that.

The **workaround** that is override `TouchesBegan` method to detect the started point whether fit your needs, and if so add `UISwipeGestureRecognizer` for View.

```
SwipeGestureRecognizer rightSwipeGesture;

public override void TouchesBegan (NSSet touches, UIEvent evt)
{
    base.TouchesBegan (touches, evt);
    UITouch touch = touches.AnyObject as UITouch;
    if (touch != null)
    {
        //code here to handle touch
         CoreGraphics.CGPoint swipPoint = touch.LocationInView(View);
         if(swipPoint.X < 0.5)
         {
            rightSwipeGesture = new SwipeGestureRecognizer { Direction = SwipeDirection.Right };
            rightSwipeGesture.Swiped += OnSwiped;
            View.AddGestureRecognizers(rightSwipeGesture);
         }
    }
}

public override void TouchesEnded (NSSet touches, UIEvent evt)
{
    base.TouchesBegan (touches, evt);
    if(null != rightSwipeGesture ){
        rightSwipeGesture.Swiped -= OnSwiped;
        View.RemoveGestureRecognizers(rightSwipeGesture);
    }
}
```

=============================Update=================================

I found a workaround only use one **GestureRecognizer** will make it works. You could have a look at [UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscreenedgepangesturerecognizer?language=objc). Although it's a Pan gesture, however if you not deal with somethind with the added view, it will work as a swip gesture. In addition, **UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer** only can work when on the screen edge. You could set the `Left` edge to handle your needs.

For example:

```
UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer panRightGestureRecognizer = new UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer();
panRightGestureRecognizer.Edges = UIRectEdge.Left;
panRightGestureRecognizer.AddTarget(() => HandleSwap(panRightGestureRecognizer));
View.AddGestureRecognizer(panRightGestureRecognizer);

private void HandleSwip(UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer panRightGestureRecognizer)
{
     Point point = (Point)panRightGestureRecognizer.TranslationInView(View);
     if (panRightGestureRecognizer.State == UGestureRecognizerState.Began)
     {
         Console.WriteLine("Show slider view");
     }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I will try to implement that today and see if it works for me. I will let you know when I did it :)

Comment: Hi, my first problem is that there is not rightSwipeGesture.Swiped for me, so I added the action in rightSwipeGesture = new SwipeGestureRecognizer(action). After I implemented it, it detects a simple touch and opens my SideMenu, even if just touch the screen and not swipe somewhere. :/ How can I change it, so that only SwipeGesture and not TouchGestures are detected?

Comment: @Ben Generally, we can use `TouchGestures` to custom all we needs, however `SwipeGesture` is a simple wrapped `TouchGestures` and `SwipeGesture` not contains methods to detect the position of finger touch. I found that `UIScreenEdgePanGestureRecognizer` may be easy to achieve that your wants.  I will update the answer.

Comment: That works! Nice. We tried so long to achieve that.